# what file architecture to follow while uploading an sdl based C++ project to Github?

Tags: c++, game-design, sdl2, project-management, git

I created this sdl game containing header files source files and graphics files including tilemaps .
I also have a setup file that will install a .exe file with dependencies such as dll files for sdl .
Which files and in which architecture should I upload this project to Github?

Comment: That's totally up to you; most people would probably consider the builds you upload to GitHub to be the "official" ones, so decide which platforms you want to officially support and upload those executables.